# How to access a child class function

Tags: c++

```
class base{}

class child : public base{

**dummyfunction();**

}
```

now I am calling a function in which I am passing a child class object.

```
**child ob;**

function(**ob**);//calling a function  

//function body

function(**base *object**)
{

**//here I want to access the function of child class. How can I do it???**

 **for example dummyfunction()**

}
```

Comment: You might get a more useful answer if you explain your intent in addition to what you're attempting.

Comment: Please reconsider which answer you would like to accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you required is downcasting.

you can acheive by making the dummyFunction as virtual in base class and then overriding this function in child class this solution would not require downcasting

otherwise you can use the method described in the below post but this is not safe to downcast

[Downcasting Method](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19642)

Answer (score 4):

You either need to put the function in the base class and make it virtual, or you need to do a type-safe down cast, using `dynamic_cast`. It is probably better to make the function a part of the interface, and have it available both in the base class and in the child class, but without more information it's hard to say. Generally speaking, though, the use of RTTI and `dynamic_cast` are indicative of poor design.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do this? If you're taking in an object of class `base`, you can't call a function of class `child`.

Comment: Since you wrote this for about 7 years ago, I think you should update your answer about the possibility of downcasting :)

Answer (score 1):

Your desires are contrary to the purpose of the data structures you're using.

You can do it with

```
child *child_object = dynamic_cast<child*>(object);
child_object -> dummyfunction();
```

but you shouldn't. Try designing your system properly instead.

Comment: It is quite common for *proper* design to require downcasting.  This being so, you can't possibly know that the OP's desires run contrary to their structures.  You shouldn't make generic claims like this without further intel.  -1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using dynamic cast you can use static_cast with references:

```
base &b = base();
static_cast<child&>(b).dummyFunction();
```

Comment: What happnes if base is not a child!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the function you want to call is

```
void f();
```

Make it *virtual* in *Base* class and **override** in *Derived* class and then call it from inside any member function of the Base class (*except* constructor!).